# Reviewing - how much you do

Tags: discussion

**This is not a complaint, but a suggestion...**

As I now have access to statistics of the review queues, I find that users are commonly only reviewing e.g. 5 posts when there are 90 posts to review. So what I am saying is **If you have the time to, please use up your reviews.** If you are skipping the other 85 posts, please ask what you can do about this.

Comment: But please *don't* rush your reviews.  It is much better to do 5 good reviews than 20 rushed ones.  Remember, review is our best chance to fix problems before they become big!

Comment: Tut if you do. Back a long time ago, I might have (a few times). After getting banned for getting too many review audits wrong, I figured, slower the better.

Comment: Also, as seth touched on, we can't review 90 posts, there is a limit of 20 every 12 hours I think, so this limits it and don't forget, we are all volunteers, people have other things to do like work.

Comment: Being a bit ignorant my question is that at which reputation should people be able to review?

Comment: @MarkKirby I think it's 24.

Comment: @rancho You can start reviewing at just 500 rep, two of the queues will be unlocked and the rest at 2k and finally you can review tags at 5k, see this page for a full list of privileges http://askubuntu.com/help/privileges

Comment: @Zacharee1 You may be right, I don't count them, just go until it tells me I reached the limit :)

Comment: @MarkKirby 24 hours, not reviews :p. 20 reviews is the limit.